# How to login a shared folder in a Workgroup from a PC in a domain?

Tags: windows, network-shares

I have 2 home computers that are in a Workgroup. Each PC has Windows and several shared folders.

I have a business computer, also with Windows. But this computer is in a domain (company domain).

If I go to Explorer -> Network I see the local workgroup computers and I also see the shared folders.

However when I try to login it says that the credentials are wrong, but they are good and accepted if I login from workgroup to workgroup.

I think my domain PC makes a mess with the domain. When I am asked for the credentials, I can read:

```
===
Enter Network Password
Enter your password to connect to [here the workgroup pc name]
___username___
___password___
Domain: [domainname]
[]Remember my credentials
Insert a smartcard
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to enter those resources when I am logged in in the domain? I see them. I don't understand why the credentials are not being accepted.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to access the workgroup share, and it pops up asking for credentials, you have to supply credentials that exist on the target workstation system, and should include the workstation's name as the "domain" so that it knows where to look to compare the credentials entered.

So say the workstation is named "HomePC", and you have a user named "PikkHome" on it with a password assigned.

So in that case, you'd enter "PikkHome" as your user name, enter that user's password, and then enter "HomePC" as the domain.

Alternatively, you can specify "HomePC\PikkHome", or "PikkHome@HomePC" as the user name to specify both the user name and the domain in one field.

Comment: Just want to add for anyone who may be doing this on a larger network, that I have had a good experience with creating an "Admin" account, with the same credentials on each PC, and using it to log on. This is not necessary, but can help a lot with not having to remember a variety of credentials. +1 to Techie007